# Is the Feichtinger's algebra $(S_0(\mathbb{R^d}),||\cdot||_{S_0})$ reflexive?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis

The Feichtinger's algebra
$S_0(\mathbb{R^d})=M^{1,1}(\mathbb{R^d}):=\{f\in L^2(\mathbb{R^d}):V_g(f)\in L^1(\mathbb{R^{2d}})\}$, where
$V_g(f)(x,\omega)$ is the short-time Fourier transform of $f$ with respect to $g \in S(\mathbb{R^d})$, which is the Schwartz space, defined by
$$
V_g(f)(x,\omega)=\int_\mathbb{R^d} f(t)\, \overline{g(t-x)}\, e^{-2\pi i\omega \cdot t} \, dt.
$$ 
Then we define the norm on $S_0(\mathbb{R^d})$:
$$
||f||_{S_0}=\int_{\mathbb{R^d}}  \left(\int_{\mathbb{R^d}}|V_gf(x,\omega)| \, dx\right)\, d\omega
$$
It's known that $(S_0(\mathbb{R^d}),||\cdot||_{S_0})$ is a Banach space, and $S(\mathbb{R^d})$ is a dense subspace of $S_0(\mathbb{R^d}).$ My question: is $(S_0(\mathbb{R^d}),||\cdot||_{S_0})$ reflexive?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No. Wilson bases (or more generally local Fourier bases) allow to identify $S_0$ with the sequence space $\ell^1$ (i.e. the elements of $S_0$ are just the functions in $L^2$ having an absolutely convergent Wilson series expansion). HENCE the space is a dual space (the pre-dual is so to say $c_0$ at the sequence space level), resp. the closure of the test functions in the dual space $S_0'$, resp. the space of all tempered distributions  which have STFTs (short time Fourier transforms) which vanish at infinity (in phase space). So, NO, it is not a reflexive space.   HGFei

Comment: Welcome to MO! Great to have you here - there are plenty of unanswered questions around for which the posters would be glad if you could take a look (see, e.g. the questions appearing on the right in a browser or try the search terms "Besov space", "Modulation space" or even "Feichtinger"!)